# Как запустить сразу несколько скриптов одним скриптом на puthon

Tags: python

То есть у меня есть несколько скриптов допустим `script1` `script2` и `script3` и мне нужно что бы запустив `all_script` у меня запустились все скрипты

Answer (score -1):

```
import os # необходимый модуль для запуска скриптов

def all_script(): # объявляем функцию
    os.system("python /path/to/script1.py")
    os.system("python /path/to/script2.py")
    os.system("python /path/to/script3.py")

all_script() # Вызываем функцию
```